# Нужно поместить на изображение текст, иконку и т.п, но при обертывание каждого изображение в доп. <div> они теряют свойства основного элемента <diva>

Tags: html, css

1 часть не обернутая

```
<div class="images">
  <div class="images_left">
    <img src="img.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="img.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="img.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="img.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="images_right">
    <img src="img.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="img.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="img.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="img.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

2 часть обернутая

```
<div class="images">
  <div class="images_left">
    <div class="foto_1">
      <img src="" alt="">
      <a href=""></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="images_left">
    <div class="foto_1">
      <img src="" alt="">
      <a href=""></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="images_left">
    <div class="foto_1">
      <img src="" alt="">
      <a href=""></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Добавьте пример того, как должно выглядеть. Лично для меня вопрос не совсем понятен.

Comment: просто в div images я вложил свойства display:flex, и justify-content:space-between, в 1 не обернутом случае они применяются к фото и они правильно располагаются по странице, во 2 обернутом  img в div они уже не наследуются и фото находятся в первоначальном виде

Comment: https://youtu.be/UK_RTvtum2Y?t=1999

Answer (score 0):

Надеюсь я правильно додумал вопрос..
Суть проблемы - изображения больше чем родительский блок.

Решение проблемы: ограничить размеры относительно родительского блока при помощи правил `max-width` и `max-height`

```css
.images {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between; 
}

.images img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="images">
  <div class="images_left">
    <div class="foto_1">
      <img src="//i.imgur.com/PNo12o4.png" alt="">
      <a href="#"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="images_left">
    <div class="foto_1">
      <img src="//i.imgur.com/PNo12o4.png" alt="">
      <a href="#"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="images_left">
    <div class="foto_1">
      <img src="//i.imgur.com/PNo12o4.png" alt="">
      <a href="#"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```